# How to trap stack overflow in a Windows x64 C++ application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to compile an application to x64 platform architecture in Windows. A couple of threads, handling the parsing of a scripting language, uses this code [recommended by Microsoft to trap stack overflows and avoid access violation exceptions](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315937):

```
__try
{
    DoSomethingThatMightUseALotOfStackMemory();
}
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
{
    LPBYTE lpPage;
    static SYSTEM_INFO si;
    static MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mi;
    static DWORD dwOldProtect;

    // Get page size of system
    GetSystemInfo(&si);

    // Find SP address
    _asm mov lpPage, esp;

    // Get allocation base of stack
    VirtualQuery(lpPage, &mi, sizeof(mi));

    // Go to page beyond current page
    lpPage = (LPBYTE)(mi.BaseAddress)-si.dwPageSize;

    // Free portion of stack just abandoned
    if (!VirtualFree(mi.AllocationBase,
                    (LPBYTE)lpPage - (LPBYTE)mi.AllocationBase,
                     MEM_DECOMMIT))
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    // Reintroduce the guard page
    if (!VirtualProtect(lpPage, si.dwPageSize, 
                        PAGE_GUARD | PAGE_READWRITE, 
                        &dwOldProtect))
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    Sleep(2000);
}
```

Unfortunately it uses one line of inline assembler to get the stack pointer. Visual Studio does not support inline assembly for x64 mode and I can't find a [compiler intrinsic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds.aspx) for getting the stack pointer neither.

Is it possible to do this in a x64 friendly manner?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89f73td2.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant : That link actually solves the problem. _resetstkoflw seems to be the call to use instead of the hack above. Maybe this should be added as a proper answer?

Comment: Feel free to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment to the question, the whole "hack" above can be replaced by the [_resetstkoflw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89f73td2.aspx) function. This works fine in both x86 and x64 mode.

The code snippet above then becomes:

```
// Filter for the stack overflow exception. This function traps
// the stack overflow exception, but passes all other exceptions through. 
int stack_overflow_exception_filter(int exception_code)
{
    if (exception_code == EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW)
    {
        // Do not call _resetstkoflw here, because at this point
        // the stack is not yet unwound. Instead, signal that the
        // handler (the __except block) is to be executed.
        return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
    }
    else
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

void example()
{
    int result = 0;
    __try
    {
        DoSomethingThatMightUseALotOfStackMemory();
    }
    __except(stack_overflow_exception_filter(GetExceptionCode()))
    {
        // Here, it is safe to reset the stack.
        result = _resetstkoflw();
    }

    // Terminate if _resetstkoflw failed (returned 0)
    if (!result)
        return 3;

    return 0;
}
```